# Access AWS Glue from local Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

*Is there any way to run local master Spark SQL queries against AWS Glue?*

Launch this code on my local PC:

```
SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
    .getOrCreate()
    .sql("show databases"); // this query isn't running against AWS Glue
```

**EDIT**
based on some examples it appears that the `hive.metastore.uris` configuration key should allow specifying a specific metastore url, however, it's not clear how to get the relevant value for glue

```
SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://???:9083")
    .getOrCreate()
    .sql("show databases"); // this query isn't running against AWS Glue
```

Comment: I think that it isn't possible, for two reasons:

 1) You can run the glue code by using UI, boto3, dev endpoints, you can also use AWS Glue Data Catalog in AWS EMR, but according to my knowledge that is all options.
 2) the Glue service bases on such technologies as Hive or Spark, but it isn't pure version of these technologies, there are limitations and this service uses its own library.

Comment: @j.b.gorski Looks like our Glue serves only as metadata store, and it doesn't transform data. So instead of mocking data for integration tests I can mock Glue reader wih S3 reader and read data directly from S3 (enforcing the same schema). The only error-prone point here is enforcing schema on CSV dataset read from S3

Comment: @j.b.gorski What's strange: `session.catalog().listDatabases()` returns `default` database with Glue's description. Spark SQL also returns `default` when I'm doing `show databases`. But it does not see another Glue's databases

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon provide this client that should solve the problem.
(didn't try it yet)

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore

Answer (score 0):

To run Spark locally with remote AWS S3 using AWS Glue Metadata Store, please follow these release notes I've created for the community after successfully building & testing the patched Hive libraries & relevant AWS Glue classes (as suggested by Ophir [in the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57963892/3075836)).

https://github.com/jirislav/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore/releases/tag/spark-3.3.0

I've shared the pre-built JARs so you don't have to do it yourself. But you can, I encourage you to do it.

---

#### TL;DR

##### Download

Make sure the `sha512sum` command succeeds.

```bash
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/jirislav/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore/releases/download/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-jars.tgz
sha512sum -c <(curl -sL https://github.com/jirislav/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore/releases/download/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-jars.tgz.sha512)
```

##### Extract

```bash
cd "$SPARK_HOME/jars"
tar -xf /tmp/spark-3.3.0-jars.tgz
```

And finally adjust `SPARK_CONF_DIR` as discussed in the release notes.